# XSLT splitting version

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML fragment like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <b version="80.70.60">
        <version1>12.13.14</version1>
    </b>
</a>
```

I want to display

> 12.13.80.70

in one of the HTML tags. basically I want to split the values in 'version' attribute and 'version1' element by a dot delimiter and consider only the first two elements from each values.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="b">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(version1, '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(version1, '.'), '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@version, '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@version, '.'), '.')"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```